# Java: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager

Tags: java, http

I created a webservice using servlet and Tomcat 6.0.
I created a java project in eclipse to call that webservice using HTTP.
I added the following jar files
1. httpcore-4.0
2. httpclient-4.0
but while running the project im getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.<init>(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:75)
at WSCall.HttpUtilities.GetServerResponse(HttpUtilities.java:52)
at WSCall.ServiceCall.main(ServiceCall.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

Please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have to add common-logging dependency under your classpath. However, you may continue encounter other simaliar Exceptions due to lack other dependency. I suggest you use maven to manage the dependency so that you don't have to mannualy add dependencies to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your project doesn't contain the [Apache Commons Logging library](http://commons.apache.org/logging/). Adding it to your classpath should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the missing of commons-logging.jar.To fix it, download the commons logging library and add it to your project.